# Trying to make a typical ajax call in zend framework 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I've been given the task of putting a file uploader into a project originally made in zend framework 2. I'm a beginner at this.

The structure of the project confuses me as it does not follow the structure of the Zend Skeleton Application I used to familiarise myself with the project. E.g. This project does not contain a module.config file.

Because of this I've resorted to using a typical ajax call, however I get a type EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER error. And I am trying to figure out how to pull a typical ajax call in ZF2.

The html and the the ajax call are:

```
<form id="fileupload"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="row">
     <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple/>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
</div>

<div id="content" class="row">
</div>

</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#fileupload').on('submit', function(e){

          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              url: "upload.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: new FormData(this),
              contentType:false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(data, textStatus){

                   $("#content").html("data: " + data + " status: " + textStatus);
              },
              error: function(data,textStatus){

                alert("data: " + data + " status: " + textStatus);              
              }
          });
      });

});

</script>
```

in the cupload.php I have:

```
<?php 

$options = array(
    'db_host' => 'hostname',
    'db_user' => 'username',
    'db_pass' => 'password',
    'db_name' => 'dbname',
    'db_table' => 'dbtable'
);

if (is_array($_FILES) ){
    // MYSQL and PHP logic goes here    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your front-end jQuery code makes a request to the back-end PHP code. In a ZF2 application, such requests are handled via routes, controllers, and actions.

So, you need to:

- add a route that will handle the upload. This will define the mapping between the url to which the client-side code (your jQuery) must make its request and the back-end controller/action which will handle the request and return a response
- implement the controller and action defined in the route
- modify your front-end code to use the url represented by the route

Different ZF2 setups achieve the first two steps - routing and controllers/actions - in different ways, but typically it is defined in an existing - or even new - module. The standard setup for such things are described in the [ZF2 docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html).